# How do I take out an object from `Object?` nullable?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm trying to make a method with optional parameter `SpriteFont = myFont` work. Because spritefont is not a compile time constant, I can't use it, so I decided to try `SpriteFont? = null`:

```
void MyMethod(int x, SpriteFont? font = null)
{
    SpriteFont f;
    if (font == null) f = defaultFont; else f = font; // Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont?' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteFont'
}
```

How do I take out my `SpriteFont` from `SpriteFont?`?

**UPD:** this *may* be a problem with types that are not convertible from nullable to base type by default. `(SpriteFont)font` still causes "cannot convert".

**UPD2:** turns out `SpriteFont` is nullable by default. Still, I now know how to work with `nonNullable?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nullable can be converted to the non nullable type by these ways:

- `(Type)variable`;
- `variable.Value`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `??` operator:

```
f = font ?? defaultFont;
```

Comment: Just tested it... it is possible for sure.

Comment: If `f` is not nullable, can you assign a nullable type (`font`) to it?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the syntax for ??: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @PinnyM: The point of the null coalescing operator is to allow you to define a default value that is within the range of the original variable type in the case that the lvalue is `null`.

Comment: Glad I'm not crazy. Thanks for commenting @PinnyM

Answer (score 4):

Use `.Value`:

```
f = font.HasValue ? font.Value : defaultFont;
```

Comment: They could also use `f = font.GetValueOrDefault(defaultFont);`

Comment: @Matthew: The null coalescing operator is usually considered more idiomatic. `f = font ?? defaultFont;`.